# Flutter Drawing a Skewed Oval Using CustomPainter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to draw this oval in Custom Painter.

[image: Oval]

I can't seem to wrap my head around it. I've tried using the `drawOval()` function on the `Canvas`:

```
    @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final startAngle = -math.pi / 2;
    final sweepAngle = math.pi;
    Offset center = Offset(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.5);
    int lineAmount = 10;
    Color paintColor = Color.fromRGBO(250, 154, 210, 1);
    Paint circlePaint = Paint()
      ..color = paintColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 5;

    // HIGHLIGHT
    canvas.drawOval(Rect.fromLTRB(50, 100, 250, 200), circlePaint);
    
  }
```

... and using the `drawArc()` function:

```
canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromLTRB(50, 100, 250, 200), startAngle, sweepAngle,
        false, circlePaint);
canvas.drawArc(Rect.fromLTRB(50, 100, 250, 200), -startAngle, -sweepAngle,
        false, circlePaint);
```

This is the result I keep on getting:

[image: result]

How can I properly draw the arc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as an option you can use canvas transformations - translate and rotate
like this:

```
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final angle = -math.pi / 4;
    Color paintColor = Color.fromRGBO(250, 154, 210, 1);
    Paint circlePaint = Paint()
      ..color = paintColor
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
      ..strokeWidth = 5;

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(size.width * 0.5, size.height * 0.5);
    canvas.rotate(angle);
    canvas.drawOval(Rect.fromCenter(center: Offset.zero, width: 50, height: 100), circlePaint);
    canvas.restore();
  }
```

[image]